# JavaScript ajax call with for loop and maintain the order of response also

Tags: javascript, closures

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    (function(val) {
        $.get('http://x.com/androidapi/clou.php?value=' + val, function(data) {
            console.log(data)
        })
    })(i)
}
```

I have my API response set to delay for 10 seconds if the value passed is 2, so the response for 2 comes late. Is the any way to synchronize the call without actually making the ajax call synchronized? The API just echoes the value back, the response I get is random with 2 at last. My desire goal is achieve output as `0 1 2 3 4`.

Comment: Either do one request then another, then another instead of all at the same time or look into jquery $.when

Comment: Send the next AJAX request in the callback function of the previous one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with [$.when()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/) and [$.Deferred()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Deferred/):

```
var deferreds = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  (function(val) {
    var dfd = $.Deferred();
    $.get('http://x.com/androidapi/clou.php?value=' + val, function(data) {
      dfd.resolve(data);
    }));
    deferreds.push(dfd);
  })(i)
}

$.when.apply(null, deferreds).done(function(){ console.log.apply(console, arguments)});
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/caeth/kqp294Lc/

Comment: thanks works, but is there any other way where we don't have to use an extra space (an array) ?